# What kind of material is this (for a shower pan) and how to remove it

Tags: bathroom, shower, remodeling, old-house, demolition

I have a house built in 1962. I want to demo the bathroom and I'm seeing this patterned sort of cement looking material (perhaps it's granite?) that is the shower pan. Is this cement? And what is the best way to remove it. Photo is from side view of wall.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Terrazzo flooring, which is marble chips poured in place with a bonding agent over a concrete floor. That looks like a sill so you should be able to whack it a few times with a sledge hammer and break it apart or break it free.

Comment: Is this safe to take a sledgehammer to? Any potential of lead or asbestos?

Comment: There shouldn't be in normal Terrazzo structures.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a mortar bed with Turkey grit instead of larger aggregate. If you are removing the shower it can be busted up.  Put a bar under one edge and a smack with a heavy hammer 3lbs or better and it will usually break (hitting over the void made by lifting) If you hit it while it is supported underneath it will only chip the surface most of the time lift it an inch or 2 and a heavy hammer can break it up. If you don’t lift it and just pound with a sludge hammer you can blow out the decking below. You can score it with a masonry grinding disk but this is really dusty.